# Bandwidth usage in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

How can I find out how my bandwidth is used in Google App Engine? I want to extract the top bandwidth hogs so I can cut down on my outgoing bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App engine logs all requests.  This includes information about the request (path, query string, wall/cpu/api time, and approximate data transfer out in kb) and the requester (IP address and (if the user is logged in) google account name).  You should be able to compute a reasonable estimate based on this information.

You can periodically [download your app's logs with appcfg](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Downloading_Logs).  How often you need to do this will be based on how much traffic your site handles.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to gather that info. Do you know of a tool which makes analysis easier? For another site I would simply plugin in AWStats or something similar.

Comment: AWStats, or anything else that analyzes apache log format logs should work just fine.

Comment: The key information here is that the log is in an Apache-like log format. Thanks!

Comment: anyone knows how to actually measure the outgoing bandwidth? the logs do not suffice IMHO (the fact the request was received and logged does not mean a response was even issued - sometimes connections are broken etc.), and since the response is sometimes dynamic, it's size might vary drastically.

Answer (score 1):

Also it may be helpful for you to review the usage from the admin console (all up and via the logs) as shown below - the link to the admin console is at https://appengine.google.com/

[image: Example App Engine Console]